# how to handle timestamp_16 in Garmin devices?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, bit-manipulation, garmin

I own a Garmin Vivosport which I use to track my activities and my sleep, and I want to run some analysis on my own heart rate data taken from the FIT files I download via Garmin Connect.

The problem is that I do not manage to align timestamps properly.

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015119/python-mixing-garmin-timestamps) but I didn't find an answer, nor could comment to add my question.

As explained [here](https://www.thisisant.com/forum/viewthread/6374/), in the FIT files the timestamp information is split into two different variables: a `timestamp` which appears every now and then, and a `timestamp_16` which is attached to every individual measurement. According to what they say, `timestamp_16` contains the lower 16 bits of the actual timestamp, so it should be combined with the higher 16 bits of the previous `timestamp`.

I am using data recorded on May 1st 2019. Files cover the 24h of the day, so the first data point is at 00:00 (I checked this in the graphic interface of Garmin Connect and things match). In this file I find this to be the first data entry of interest:

```
monitoring
 * activity_type: sedentary
 * current_activity_type_intensity: (8,)
 * intensity: 0
 * timestamp: 2019-04-30 22:00:00

[some other lines in between]

monitoring
 * heart_rate: 72
 * timestamp_16: 31132
```

the first `monitoring` object in the above snipped si the last one containing a `timestamp` before the one containing the heart rate, so it matches what is written in the linked instructions.

With these informations, I tried a few solution but with none of them I managed to get the actual timestamp of the first data point in the file to be at 00:00 on May 1st 2019 (nor within a few minutes).

If I follow the instructions given in the above link, I get:

```
mesgTimestamp = timestamp
mesgTimestamp += ( timestamp_16 - ( mesgTimestamp & 0xFFFF ) ) & 0xFFFF
```

but the outcome is: `2019-05-01 12:49:00`

I also tried to replace by hand the lower 16 bits of `timestamp` with `timestamp_16`, but again no success:

```
timestamp    :   0b1011100110010001011111001011000
timestamp_16 :                   0b111100110011100
result       :   0b1011100110010000111100110011100
```

The `datetime` value corresponding to the above `result` is `datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 18, 36, 44)`.

[Here](https://github.com/francescolosterzo/parse-garmin-heartrate/blob/master/TestFitparse.ipynb) is the code with all my attempts.
[Here](https://github.com/dtcooper/python-fitparse/issues/46) is a github issue where this is being discussed.

As you can see above I cannot get the right result, i.e. May 1st 2019 00:00. In addition to this, if I apply Garmin's recipe by hand at the bit level I get a different result compared to what I get applying the formula they give.

Also, the results that I get are off by an amount of time having non zero minutes and seconds, and this makes me believe that this is not a timezone issue (I also tried to play with it with no success).

Has anyone found a stable solution to this? Could you please share something, if you have it (also in other languages, I am interested in the logic here)?

I am trying to get this right since a few months (working on this during my spare time), but this lack of result is really depressing :\

Comment: Just a thought, is a timezone being applied to the date? Working in a browser with date-times frustrates me as it just always likes to add your local timezone when writing to console, and to stringing dates.

Comment: @Gauthier as I mentioned I tried to include timezones in my tests, but it didn't bring any improvement. On the other hand a 5 hours, 23 minutes 16 seconds difference does not match any timezone difference I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the special Garmin epoch into account, it's 631065600 seconds later than the Unix timestamp epoch, the calculations need to happen in that special time (if it was just a normal offset that wouldn't be the case, but these offsets are not strictly additive so the "absolute value" of the time matters). Just subtract 631065600:

```
dt_offset = datetime.datetime(2019,4,30,22,0,0,0)
timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(dt_offset)) - 631065600
timestamp_16 = 31132
```

Apply the time delta in any reasonable way, for example:

```
mesgTimestamp = timestamp
mesgTimestamp += ( timestamp_16 - ( mesgTimestamp & 0xFFFF ) ) & 0xFFFF
```

Or:

```
mesgTimestamp = timestamp + ((timestamp_16 - timestamp) & 0xffff)
```

Or:

```
mesgTimestamp = (timestamp & 0xffff0000) | timestamp_16
if mesgTimestamp < timestamp:
  mesgTimestamp += 0x10000
```

Apply the Garmin epoch-offset again when using the resulting timestamp:

```
print('New:', datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mesgTimestamp + 631065600, pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')))
```

Result: `New: 2019-05-01 00:01:00+02:00` Close enough?

Comment: yes, this is the trick! I started suspecting that the Garmin offset was applied to the 32-bit timestamp but not to the 16-bit one and when I tried to go that way I found the trick :)

Comment: is someone used to R AND Python and could explain how it should be done in R?  Especially this: mesgTimestamp = timestamp + ((timestamp_16 - timestamp) & 0xffff)